# Converting SQL Server stored procedure to Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am migrating my application from SQL Server to Postgres 11. I am not able to find any solution for migrating procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DeleteAttachmentsForArtefacts] 
    @artefactTypeId BIGINT, 
    @artefactIds IdListTable READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE tbl_Resources_Attachment 
    WHERE ContextTypeId = @artefactTypeId 
      AND ContextId IN (SELECT Id FROM @artefactIds)    
END

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdListTable] AS TABLE
(
  [Id] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
```

I have created userdefined type in Postgres. But it is not working in "select Id from @artefactIds". It is giving error "artefactIds" doesn't exit.

Comment: Unrelated, but: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/is-adding-the-tbl-prefix-to-table-names-really-a-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any special type for this, you can simply pass an array:

```
create or replace procedure sp_deleteattachmentsforartefacts(p_artefact_id integer, p_idlist integer[]) 
as
$$
begin

  delete from tbl_Resources_Attachment 
  where ContextTypeId = p_artefact_id 
    and ContextId = any(p_idlist);

end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

To run it, call it like this:

```
call sp_DeleteAttachmentsForArtefacts(42, array[1,2,3,4]);
```

Comment: With this solution I am facing one problem now. I am not able to get below result in case of postgres.

declare discussionIds IdListTable

insert into discussionIds select Id from tbl_Notification_Discussion where ContextTypeId = artefactTypeId

Here I can get multiple records from table and able to store it into userdefined datatype.

Comment: @Hardik: please ask a new question. But it sounds as if you want a `select array_agg(...) from ...` to retrieve the IDs as an array. But the whole thing sounds rather strange. Why can't the delete procedure run that subselect? Pass huge lists of IDs around is a questionable design.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function as Procedures are not fully added in PostgreSQl

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS source;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sp_DeleteAttachmentsForArtefacts(integer,IdListTable);
DROP TYPE IdListTable;

CREATE TYPE IdListTable AS (
    id INTEGER
   ,t  TIMESTAMP
   ,x  FLOAT
);



CREATE TABLE source OF IdListTable (PRIMARY KEY(Id));
INSERT INTO source VALUES
    (1, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 10.0)
   ,(2, '2016-01-01 00:30:00', 11.0)
   ,(3, '2016-01-01 01:00:00', 12.0)
   ,(4, '2016-01-01 01:30:00',  9.0)
   ;


create or replace function sp_DeleteAttachmentsForArtefacts(artefactTypeId integer,_source IdListTable ) returns integer as
$$
begin

delete from tbl_Resources_Attachment where ContextTypeId = artefactTypeId and ContextId in (select Id from source);

return 1;

end
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: I don't want separate table to store records. "IdListTable" shoud be pass as parameter and I should be able to pass multiple records to this. Still I didn't get solution to pass multiple parameter. I can pass ROW(1, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 10.0).